# tooltip not showing bar chart D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, transition, bounce

I'm pretty new in `D3.js` (I'm a `R` programmer) and I want to make a simple bar chart based on Aravind's [example](https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden/d04238c4c9770020ff6867ee92c7dac1) with a start transition and add a tooltip.

The problem is when the tooltip works, the transition doesn't (and vice versa).

Here's is what I've tried so far (the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0ven6x/)):

```
var easeOutBounce = function(pos) {
  if ((pos) < (1 / 2.75)) {
    return (7.5625 * pos * pos);
  }
  if (pos < (2 / 2.75)) {
    return (7.5625 * (pos -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * pos + 0.75);
  }
  if (pos < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
    return (7.5625 * (pos -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * pos + 0.9375);
  }
  return (7.5625 * (pos -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * pos + 0.984375);
};

Math.easeOutBounce = easeOutBounce;

var t = d3.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .ease(easeOutBounce)

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 10
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// set x axis margin
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([30, width])
  .padding(0.1);

// set y axis margin
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");

d3.tsv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patarol/d3_sketch/master/data/data.tsv").then(function(data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return Number(d.value);
  })]);

  // draw x axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // draw y axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0" + 30 + ")")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
      .ticks(5)
      .tickFormat(d3.format(".0s")))
    .style("font-size", "10px")
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Value")
    .style("font-size", "12px");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.name);
      })
      .attr("y", height)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease(easeOutBounce)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(Number(d.value));
      })

      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(Number(d.value));
      });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you don't anything with the `div.tooltip`

Comment: thank you @rioV8. It helped me a lot!